# Using standard or custom date formats

Tags: c#, datetime, date-formatting

The following code:

```
DateTime test = new DateTime();
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("d"));
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("d_"));
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("dd"));
```

Produces the following results:

```
0001-01-01
1_
01
```

The first result is full date, because `d` is being treated as a standard date format. On the other hand, `d_` is treated as custom date format and in such case d is treated as short day string. Is there a way to generate only short day without underscore?

Comment: What formatting string should I use if for date, say, 2015-09-01 I'd like to get the result `1`?

Comment: You could use `test.Day` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, that's a workaround, not solution.

Comment: It's a comment not an answer

Comment: This is also true...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of these:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("%d"));
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString(" d"));
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("d "));
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format specifier by itself), **include a space before or after the specifier, or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom date and time specifier**.

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("%d"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there are only workarounds for this issue. You want to be `date.ToString("d")` interpreted as a [custom date time format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dSpecifier) which shows the day. But per definition  a single format specifier always specifies a [standard date and time format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could directly use `DateTime.Day`:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Day);
```

or this trick which uses `d` with an empty space + `Trim`:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString(" d ").Trim());
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A standard date and time format string **uses a single format specifier**
>   to define the text representation of a date and time value. **Any date
>   and time format string that contains more than one character,
>   including white space, is interpreted as a custom date and time format
>   string**